# Efficient way to fill missing values using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of a million rows

The dataframe includes the columns ID, FDAT, LACT

For each ID there may be multiple FDAT and LACT.  The FDAT should be the same for each LACT for that ID.  Occasionally there is a missing FDAT which I want to fill with the matching FDAT from that ID for that LACT

example data

```
ID  FDAT      LACT
1   1/1/2020    1
1   1/1/2020    1
1   1/1/2021    2
1   NA          2
1   1/1/2021    2
1   1/1/2022    3
```

In this example the NA should be 1/1/2021

I am using the following code to do this.  Unfortunately it is very slow.  I only want to fill the missing values.  I do not want to change any of the nonnull FDAT entries.

```
df.sort_values(["ID",'DATE'], inplace=True)

df.loc[:, 'FDAT'] = df.groupby(['ID','LACT']).fillna(method="ffill")
df.loc[:, 'FDAT'] = df.groupby(['ID','LACT']).fillna(method="bfill")
```

I was looking for code that would do the same thing but run faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some vectorized code to handle this. It processes 1 million rows in under a second.

```py
def fillna_fdat(df):
    a = df.set_index(['ID', 'LACT'])['FDAT']
    b = a.dropna()
    return df.assign(
        FDAT=a.fillna(b[~b.index.duplicated(keep='first')]).to_numpy()
    )
```

Applied to your example input data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'FDAT': [
        '1/1/2020', '1/1/2020', '1/1/2021', float('nan'),
        '1/1/2021', '1/1/2022'],
    'LACT': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
})

>>> fillna_fdat(df)
   ID      FDAT  LACT
0   1  1/1/2020     1
1   1  1/1/2020     1
2   1  1/1/2021     2
3   1  1/1/2021     2
4   1  1/1/2021     2
5   1  1/1/2022     3
```

#### Explanation

The basic idea is to make a clean mapping of `(ID, LACT): FDAT`. To do that efficiently, we use a version of `df` where the index is made of `[ID, LACT]`:

```py
a = df.set_index(['ID', 'LACT'])['FDAT']
>>> a
ID  LACT
1   1       1/1/2020
    1       1/1/2020
    2       1/1/2021
    2            NaN
    2       1/1/2021
    3       1/1/2022
```

We drop `NaN` values, and duplicated indices:

```py
b = a.dropna()
c = b[~b.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
>>> c
ID  LACT
1   1       1/1/2020
    2       1/1/2021
    3       1/1/2022
```

Now, we can replace all `NaN`s in `a` by the values from `c` for the same index `['ID', 'LACT']`:

```py
d = a.fillna(b[~b.index.duplicated(keep='first')])
>>> d
ID  LACT
1   1       1/1/2020
    1       1/1/2020
    2       1/1/2021
    2       1/1/2021  <-- this was filled from d.loc[(1,2)]
    2       1/1/2021
    3       1/1/2022
```

At this point, we just want to get those values, which are in the same order as in the original `df`, and ignore the index as we replace `df['FDAT']` with those (hence the `.to_numpy()` part). In order to leave the original `df` unmodified (I strongly resent any code that changes my inputs unless explicitly stated so), we derive a new `df` using the idiom `df.assign(FDAT=...)`, and return that. Putting it all together, that gives the function above.

#### Other observations

Note that other columns, if any, are preserved. To show this, and to measure performance, let's write a generator of random `df`:

```py
def gen(n, k=None):
    nhalf = n // 2
    k = n // 3 if k is None else k
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID': np.random.randint(0, k, nhalf),
        'FDAT': [f'1/1/{y}' for y in np.random.randint(2010, 2012+k, nhalf)],
        'LACT': np.random.randint(0, k, nhalf),
    })
    df = pd.concat([
        df,
        df.assign(FDAT=np.nan),
    ]).sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True).assign(
        other=np.random.uniform(size=2*nhalf)
    )
    return df
```

Small example:

```py
np.random.seed(0)  # reproducible example
df = gen(10)

>>> df
   ID      FDAT  LACT     other
0   0  1/1/2010     2  0.957155
1   1  1/1/2014     0  0.140351
2   1  1/1/2010     2  0.870087
3   1       NaN     1  0.473608
4   0       NaN     2  0.800911
5   0  1/1/2012     2  0.520477
6   1       NaN     2  0.678880
7   1       NaN     0  0.720633
8   0       NaN     2  0.582020
9   1  1/1/2014     1  0.537373

>>> fillna_fdat(df)
   ID      FDAT  LACT     other
0   0  1/1/2010     2  0.957155
1   1  1/1/2014     0  0.140351
2   1  1/1/2010     2  0.870087
3   1  1/1/2014     1  0.473608
4   0  1/1/2010     2  0.800911
5   0  1/1/2012     2  0.520477
6   1  1/1/2010     2  0.678880
7   1  1/1/2014     0  0.720633
8   0  1/1/2010     2  0.582020
9   1  1/1/2014     1  0.537373
```

#### Speed

```py
np.random.seed(0)
df = gen(1_000_000)

%timeit fillna_fdat(df)
# 806 ms ± 13.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Under a second for 1 million rows.

Comment: Pierre I am very interested in your function. I am afraid it is a bit ahead of my level of expertise.  Could you please provide a description of what each line does.  Thank you

Comment: Fair enough; I added a bit of explanation. Try to follow the same steps with a slightly larger (and maybe unordered) example, to better familiarize yourself with what's going on in that code.

Answer (score 1):

As you see below, I give you a much faster alternative, together with your orginal and computation times:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        'FDAT': ['1/1/2020', '1/1/2020', '1/1/2021', None, '1/1/2021', '1/1/2022'],
        'LACT': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
import time

start_time = time.time()

df.sort_values(["ID", "FDAT", "LACT"], inplace=True)
df["FDAT"] = df.groupby(["ID", "LACT"])["FDAT"].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(method="ffill"))

print(df)

end_time = time.time()
print("Execution time:", end_time - start_time, "seconds")
```

returning:

```
   ID      FDAT  LACT
0   1  1/1/2020     1
1   1  1/1/2020     1
2   1  1/1/2021     2
4   1  1/1/2021     2
5   1  1/1/2022     3
3   1  1/1/2021     2
Execution time: 0.008013486862182617 seconds
```

while you solution:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        'FDAT': ['1/1/2020', '1/1/2020', '1/1/2021', None, '1/1/2021', '1/1/2022'],
        'LACT': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
import time

start_time = time.time()

df.loc[:, 'FDAT'] = df.groupby(['ID','LACT']).fillna(method="ffill")
df.loc[:, 'FDAT'] = df.groupby(['ID','LACT']).fillna(method="bfill")
print(df)

end_time = time.time()
print("Execution time:", end_time - start_time, "seconds")
```

returns:

```
   ID      FDAT  LACT
0   1  1/1/2020     1
1   1  1/1/2020     1
2   1  1/1/2021     2
3   1  1/1/2021     2
4   1  1/1/2021     2
5   1  1/1/2022     3
Execution time: 0.011833429336547852 seconds
```

So, using `transform` together with `fffill`is approximately 1.5 times faster. Note, that `sort_values()` is excluded from the time in your code example. So, I'd reckon it should be up to 2.5 times faster to use the method I suggest.